# Can I call a cd "the book's audio"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I have a cd that accompanies an English textbook. This cd contains the audio of the conversations and the listening exercises. Can I call this cd the book's audio as in I don't have the book's audio?

Answer (score 1):

> The book's audio

will have the meaning that it is an "*audio*" recording of the entire book, as in an *audio* book.  In your case the CD is

> the book's **supplemental** audio CD

which is a CD included in the course work of the book. The same would be true of

> **supplemental** workbooks
>   **supplemental** flash cards